# Как полученное сообщение поместить в переменную telebot

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_message(message):
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
  return message

bot.send_message(send_message().from_user.id, "Другой текст") # Error missing 'message'
```

мне нужно это сообщение для определения chat id, чтобы вне функции отсылать сообщения независимо от того ввел что-то пользователь или нет.

Comment: забейте я дурачок, забыл  как функции работают